# multiple async calls return boolean but do not wait

Tags: angular, asynchronous

The problem I'm facing is that when using the searchbar, it shows "No results found" before it actually shows results.
this is not a frontend issue, since all the calls are async, one without results finishes before the others with results do, resulting in a visual bug.

im trying to return a `boolean True` when all my async calls are finished.
but I don't really know how to tackle this.

the reason I'd like to keep them all async is because when searching, I want results asap on the page, while it continues to search for other results.

this is the code:

```
private loadResults(): void {
if (!this.query || !this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds) {
  return;
}

this.results = null;
this.repository
  .searchFreelancers(this.query, this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds)
  .subscribe((model) => {

    this.results = this.results === null ? 0 : this.results;

    this.freelancers = model;
    this.results = this.results + this.freelancers.length;

    this.isBusy = this.results === 0 ? false : true;
  });

this.repository
  .searchAssignments(this.query, this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds)
  .subscribe((model) => {

    this.results = this.results === null ? 0 : this.results;

    this.assignments = model;
    this.results = this.results + this.assignments.length;
    this.isBusy = this.results === 0 ? false : true;
  });

this.repository
  .searchPrincipals(this.query, this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds)
  .subscribe((model) => {

    this.results = this.results === null ? 0 : this.results;

    this.principals = model;
    this.results = this.results + this.principals.length;
    this.isBusy = this.results === 0 ? false : true;
  });

this.repository
  .searchManagers(this.query, this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds)
  .subscribe((model) => {

    this.results = this.results === null ? 0 : this.results;

    this.managers = model;
    this.results = this.results + this.managers.length;
    this.isBusy = this.results === 0 ? false : true;
  });

this.repository
  .searchBills(this.query, this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds)
  .subscribe((model) => {

    this.results = this.results === null ? 0 : this.results;

    this.bills = model;
    this.results = this.results + this.bills.length;
    this.isBusy = this.results === 0 ? false : true;
  });

this.repository
  .searchUsers(this.query, this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds)
  .subscribe((model) => {

    this.users = model;
    this.results = this.results + this.users.length;

    this.principalUsers = model.filter(u => u.roleId == 2);
    this.intermediaryUsers = model.filter(u => u.roleId == 7);
    this.isBusy = this.results === 0 ? false : true;
  });

this.repository
  .searchIntermediaries(this.query, this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds)
  .subscribe((model) => {

    this.results = this.results === null ? 0 : this.results;

    this.intermediaries = model;
    this.results = this.results + this.intermediaries.length;
    this.isBusy = this.results === 0 ? false : true;
  });

this.repository
  .searchOperatingCompanyUsers(this.query, this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds)
  .subscribe((model) => {

    this.results = this.results === null ? 0 : this.results;

    this.operatingCompanyUsers = model
    this.results = this.results + this.operatingCompanyUsers.length;
    this.isBusy = this.results === 0 ? false : true;
  });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forkJoin, it will trigger once all the subscriptions are received so you can do the things inside that forkjoin subscription and return the values.

here is the example usage of the forkJoin with your code.

```
forkJoin({
  requestOne: this.repository.searchFreelancers(this.query, this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds),
  requestTwo: this.repository.searchAssignments(this.query, this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds),
  requestThree: this.repository.searchPrincipals(this.query, this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds)
})
.subscribe(({requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree}) => {
  if(requestOne && requestTwo && requestThree){
    return true 
  };
});
```

for more information please refer [forkJoin official page](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

Comment: do you know any other ways without react?

Comment: This is not react this is angular RxJS implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Prabath's answer, you can start with a fork join, but return the observable instead. Then, on your template, you can use an async pipe.

```
private loadResults(): Observable<boolean> {

    const query: string = this.query  
    const soci: string = this.selectedOperatingCompanyIds

    return forkJoin({
        r1: this.repository.searchFreelancers(query, soci),
        r2: this.repository.searchAssignments(query, soci),
        r3: this.repository.searchPrincipals(query, soci),
        r4: this.repository.searchManagers(query, soci),
        r5: this.repository.searchBills(query, soci),
        r6: this.repository.searchUsers(query, soci),
        r7: this.repository.searchIntermediaries(query, soci),
        r8: this.repository.searchOperatingCompanyUsers(query, soci),
    }).pipe(map(r => {
        return true
    });    
}
```